# Time measuring in C program

Tags: c, time, sys, measure, time.h

I need to measure **real** and **virtual** (CPU) time of loop execution. This loop includes multiprocessing and child processes.
I tried with CPU:

```
clock_t start, end;
cpu_time_used=((double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC); //in sec
```

and for real time:

```
struct timeval tv1, tv2;     
gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);  
gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);  
printf("Total time = %f sec. \n", (double)(tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000000) + (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec));
```

But the measurements are not adequate. As far as I understand the CPU time should be a bit longer in this case, but there is almost no difference between them.

Comment: **why** should CPU time be anything in relation the time difference, besides less than or equal to number of cores times wall clock delta

Comment: Also, where do you initialize the `start`, `end`?

Comment: didn't put it there but I initialize start = clock() before the loop and then end it just after (end=clock()).